# Convert two images into a pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, pdf, pdfsharp

I want to convert 2 images into a single pdf file.One image is big in size and small image on the top of the big image.
So In generated pdf also I need to show the small image on the top of the big image and also in the same position where it is in case of image.

I use pdfSharp to convert image to pdf.It will convert the images into pdf file but not able to position the second image on the top of the first image.
Can any one help me on that.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the code you currently have.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the sample below and see if it's what you need:
http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=34&Itemid=45